# Expecting numeric in B2 / R2C2: got a date in R

Tags: r

I am reading in a data set from excel that has dates in it. When I read my code it gives me this warning: "Expecting numeric in B2 / R2C2: got a date"

All of my dates are messed up. how do I solve this?

Comment: May I suggest you re-write your question Adding the R code used to read in the file. Provide more info on what type of file, .csv, .xls, etc. Try adding the smallest bit of code that will [RE-Produce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also consider reading this [Checklist for writing good questions](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 4):

It helps us to help you if you show the exact code that you used, including any packages used.

That warning looks like it comes from the readxl package (but could be a different package).

Basically, when functions like `read_xl` or even `read.table` are not told specifically what type of data is in each column then R will read several rows at the top of the file and make an educated guess as to what type of data is in each column, then it will start over and read the data based on those guesses.

Your warning means that there was a cell that your R function was expecting to be a number (based either on the educated guess, or because you told it to expect a number) and instead it saw a date, so it gives a warning to let you know that there was a potential problem.  Note that a warning means the code continued to run, there may just be some values that don't match what you were expecting.  An error would have stopped the code running and not returned anything.

To fix the problem you can either explicitly tell your R function what type of data is in each column (exactly how depends on the function).  Or you can fix your Excel file so that it is clear what each type of data is (remember, just because something looks like a date in Excel does not mean that Excel realizes it is a date or tells other programs that it is a date).

Comment: I am mystified why you would answer this when you yourself realize the question needs much work? Why not flag it? I mean no disrespect, just puzzled.

Comment: @oaxacamatt, Different people respond differently to levels of help.  There is the original poster, but there could also be other people who see a similar error message and find this question by searching (at it is not their fault the question is not detailed enough).  I agree that the best option is for the poster to improve the question, show code etc.  But some people may be turned off by a short comment telling them to rewrite the question and not come back, but seeing some willingness to help may inspire better questions in the future.

Comment: Hi Greg, Fair enough, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This warning usually tells you, that the value in cell B2 (in Excel) has an unexpected value (a date instead of numeric value). Check the value in cell B2 in the Excel file.